# SQL select only last entry of date from a calculated field

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hey I'm trying to visualize a past 30 days trend as a line graph in metabase and therefore have to query the data in a right way.

The table looks like this:

```
    DATE                          SCORE
September 7, 2019, 12:00 AM         3
September 7, 2019, 12:00 AM         4
September 8, 2019, 12:00 AM         9
September 9, 2019, 12:00 AM         10
```

I tried this query which calculates the NPS and the rolling sum over the last 30 rows.

```
select DATE, 
        CASE
            WHEN SCORE <= 6 THEN '-1'
            WHEN SCORE <= 8 THEN '0'
            WHEN SCORE > 8 THEN '1'
        END AS NPS
        ,SUM(NPS) OVER(ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS NPSTotal
FROM Table;
```

Which looks like this

```
    DATE                          NPS    NPSTotal
September 7, 2019, 12:00 AM         -1    -1
September 7, 2019, 12:00 AM         -1    -2
September 8, 2019, 12:00 AM         1     -1
September 9, 2019, 12:00 AM         1      0
```

However, if I want to plot the results in metabase and put the date on the x-axis it naturally aggregates the NPSTotal, giving me a -3 for the 7 September instead of -2. I think the result of my query should look like this.

```
    DATE                        NPSTotal
September 7, 2019, 12:00 AM       -2
September 8, 2019, 12:00 AM       -1
September 9, 2019, 12:00 AM        0
```

So I need two things:
1. Sum the NPS over the date of the column and all votes from the last 30 days instead of rows.
2. The output should give out only one NPSTotal entry per date, which should be the last value.

Would be happy if somebody has a solution for this.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Use a row number partitioned in the same way as your nps  sum but ordered by date desc and on an outer query select only rows where that row number is 1. Also wish to point out you said ORDER BY DATE but your 7th Sep dates are identical so which one you'll get is not deterministic. Add more clauses to your ordering depending on what you think "last" means

Comment: @pe7e . . . Does your query really work?  Is NPS a column in the table?

Comment: thanks for the responses!
GordonLinoff: it does, the NPS column gets created with the case when thing
Yogesh Sharma: added it!
CaiusJard: that's a good advice, I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per date, then use aggregation.  That would seem to be:

```
SELECT DATE, MIN(NPSTotal) as NPSTotal
FROM (SELECT DATE, 
             (CASE WHEN SCORE <= 6 THEN '-1'
                   WHEN SCORE <= 8 THEN '0'
                   WHEN SCORE > 8 THEN '1'
              END) AS NPS,
             SUM(NPS) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS NPSTotal
     FROM Table
    ) t
GROUP BY DATE;
```

It is unclear how to resolve ties in your data.  This uses `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we calculate nps and bucket by date.
I'm assuming NPS is net promoter score. I'd tend to calculate the overall NPS in one go then plot the actual value rather than the relative daily values because it also depends on how many people are responding. If you have one responder on day 1 and 100 responders on day 2, then the single responder on day 1 will skew the NPS.

```
select date(scored_at),
       ((sum(if(score>8,1,0))/count(*))-(sum(if(score<7,1,0))/count(*)))*100 as nps
from nps_scores
where score is not null
and [date comparators can go here]
group by date(scored_At)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use in Mode to show NPS over many window sizes, over the last while but also only show windows where the start of the window is after the time point where we start collecting data.

```
WITH scores AS (
  SELECT score, date_Created::date AS date
  FROM db_name.nps.survey_answers
), days AS (
    SELECT column1 AS days FROM (values (1),(14),(35),(91),(105))
), wins_end AS (
    SELECT dateadd('day',ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SEQ8()),current_date) as win_date_end
    FROM table(generator(rowcount => 365*2.5))
), wins AS (
    SELECT d.days
        ,w.win_date_end
        ,dateadd('day',-d.days, w.win_date_end) AS win_date_start
    FROM days AS d
    JOIN wins_end AS w
)
SELECT w.days::text AS days
    ,w.win_date_end
    ,w.win_date_start
    ,AVG(score) AS a_score
    ,SUM(iff(score > 8,1,0)) AS promoter
    ,SUM(iff(score = 7 or score = 8,1,0)) AS pASsive
    ,SUM(iff(score < 7,1,0)) AS detractor
    ,COUNT(*) AS total
    ,ROUND((100*promoter/total)-(100*detractor/total),1) AS nps  
FROM scores AS s
JOIN wins w ON s.date >= w.win_date_start AND s.date <= w.win_date_end
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING win_date_start >= '2017-06-01'
```

This gives to a sliding window start/end for each window size for the last 2.5 years (that bit could be made simpler) and the calculates the NPS for the window against the data set.

Comment: seq8() can have gaps in theory

Comment: so true, should really be ROW_NUMBER(), I was using Mode to graph this, and it "handles gaps" but if you doing this a lot, or need it to be gap free. Very good point.

Comment: @waldente cheers for the point, have swapped to ROW_NUMBER to make safer.